# Progress Bar Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Forms in MS Access are really just special glorified classes, so you can create new instances of them from code like this.

> ```
> Dim someForm as Form_Form1
> set someForm = New Form_Form1
> someForm.visible = true
> ```

I decided to take advantage of this and create a progress bar form to display during long running processes. I created a form named `ProgressBar` with a rectangle and a text box.

- txtStatus
- boxProgress

[image: progress bar form in design view]

#### Form ProgressBar

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Class: Form_ProgressBar
' Popup progress bar

Private Const MaxBoxWidth As Long = 7200

Public Enum ePBarModeType
    PBarMode_Percent = 0
    PBarMode_Executing = 1
End Enum

Private mMode As ePBarModeType
Private mCurrentProgress As Long
Private mSteps As Long

Public Property Get PercentComplete() As Double
'read only
    PercentComplete = mCurrentProgress / mSteps * 100
End Property

Public Property Let Mode(PBarMode As ePBarModeType)
    mMode = PBarMode
End Property

Public Property Get Mode() As ePBarModeType
    Mode = mMode
End Property

Public Property Let CurrentProgress(lng As Long)
' Updating the CurrentProgress property updates the status of the Progress Bar

    mCurrentProgress = lng
    ' format #0 makes a 1 or 2 digit number without decimals
    If mMode = PBarMode_Percent Then
        Me.txtStatus = Format(Me.PercentComplete, "#0") & " % Complete"
    ElseIf mMode = PBarMode_Executing Then
        Me.txtStatus = "Executing..."
    End If
    ' boxProgress.Width = a percentage of maximum box width
    Me.boxProgress.Width = (mCurrentProgress / mSteps) * MaxBoxWidth
    Me.Repaint
    DoEvents
End Property

Public Property Get CurrentProgress() As Long
    CurrentProgress = mCurrentProgress
End Property

Property Let steps(lng As Long)
    mSteps = lng
End Property

Public Sub init(steps As Long, Mode As ePBarModeType, Optional strCaption As String = "Loading...")
    Me.Mode = Mode
    Me.Caption = strCaption
    mCurrentProgress = 0
    mSteps = steps
    Me.txtStatus = "Ready"
    Me.boxProgress.Width = 0
    Me.Visible = True
End Sub
```

#### Example Calls

```
Private Sub exampleCall1()
' example call for using progress bar with a looping process
    Dim pbar As Form_ProgressBar
    Dim i As Long
    Dim steps As Long
    steps = 100000

    Set pbar = New Form_ProgressBar
    With pbar
        .init steps, PBarMode_Percent, "Hey, I'm working here!"
        For i = 1 To steps
            ' do something in a loop

            ' update progress
            .CurrentProgress = i
        Next i
    End With
    Set pbar = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub exampleCall2()
' example call for using progress bar with an adodb.command
    Dim bimic As New BiMic_Wrapper
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

   DoCmd.HourGlass True

    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = bimic.Connection
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        .CommandText = "dbo.uspSomeStoredProcedure"
    End With

    'must execute command async
    cmd.Execute , , adAsyncExecute

    Dim pbar As New Form_ProgressBar
    Dim i As Long
    pbar.init 10000, PBarMode_Executing, ""

    Do While cmd.STATE = adStateExecuting
        For i = 0 To 10000
            pbar.CurrentProgress = i
        Next i
    Loop
    Set pbar = Nothing

    DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

### Concerns

- Am I really gaining anything from using a full fledged property for `Mode`? It's a simple Get & Let. Would it be cleaner to simply use a Public variable instead?
- Am I doing enough to ensure that the status doesn't display anything stupid? (Like displaying 103% complete.)
- I feel like this is a little obscure. I was thinking of splitting the logic into a private function with a decent name. Is it worth it? What would you name it?

  ```
  ' boxProgress.Width = a percentage of maximum box width
  Me.boxProgress.Width = (mCurrentProgress / mSteps) * MaxBoxWidth
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Would it be cleaner to simply use a Public variable instead?*

You're not really asking that question. I'm not really telling you that a property is always going to be cleaner than exposing a public field. ...*Well look at that, I just did!*

Point is, yes, any property could also be a public field. Heck, any public field might as well be a global variable instead. See where I'm going? Encapsulation is awesome, embrace it ;)

> *feel like this is a little obscure. I was thinking of splitting the logic into a private function with a decent name. Is it worth it?*
>
> ```
> ' boxProgress.Width = a percentage of maximum box width
>   Me.boxProgress.Width = (mCurrentProgress / mSteps) * MaxBoxWidth
> ```

All by itself, I see nothing *obscure* about this line; I'm not even sure I'd have that explanatory comment. But if you zoom out a little, and include a bit of context here...

> ```
> Public Property Let CurrentProgress(lng As Long)
> ' Updating the CurrentProgress property updates the status of the Progress Bar
>
>     mCurrentProgress = lng
>     ' format #0 makes a 1 or 2 digit number without decimals
>     If mMode = PBarMode_Percent Then
>         Me.txtStatus = Format(Me.PercentComplete, "#0") & " % Complete"
>     ElseIf mMode = PBarMode_Executing Then
>         Me.txtStatus = "Executing..."
>     End If
>     ' boxProgress.Width = a percentage of maximum box width
>     Me.boxProgress.Width = (mCurrentProgress / mSteps) * MaxBoxWidth
>     Me.Repaint
>     DoEvents
> End Property
> ```

It's a property setter! I think a setter's job ends here:

> ```
>     mCurrentProgress = lng
> ```

The rest of what happens in that `Let`-setter belongs in another method, perhaps something like... `Refresh`?

```
Public Property Let CurrentProgress(ByVal value As Long)
' Updating the CurrentProgress property updates the status of the Progress Bar

    mCurrentProgress = value
    Refresh

End Property
```

I wouldn't stop at `Refresh` - you have an `Enum` type, but you're `If-ElseIf`ing through it. Use a `Select Case` here, Mr. Maintainer will like you when he needs to add a `PBarMode_ManualCaption` execution mode that displays an ad-hoc progress message ("*Reticulating splines...*") at each step; if there's a dedicated `UpdateProgressMessage` public method, it's even easier.

Your current implementation will [re-]set the `Executing...` text at every update in progress; I would make that message mode only update the progress message once instead.

And `lng` isn't a very good name for a value that represents progress. I like having a convention that properties *themselves* define the meaning of their paramater value with their name, so all my property [let-]setters take a `value` parameter. Maybe I'm just being lazy with naming though. But `lng` looks like a disemvoweled `long`... which looks like a *Hungarian* prefix without an actual variable name, a bit like `str` for a `String`.

So to recap on the `CurrentProgress` property, I would:

- Rename the parameter to `value`, and pass it `ByVal` instead of implicitly `ByRef`.
- Extract an `UpdateProgressMessage` method, to determine the status text.
- Extract an `UpdateProgressValue` method, to determine the length/value of the progress bar.
- Extract an `Update` or `Refresh` method, to call the other two extracted method:

  ```
  Private Sub Refresh()

      UpdateProgressMessage
      UpdateProgressValue

      Me.Repaint
      DoEvents

  End Sub
  ```

---

I cringe whenever I see a variable, field or property that's just called `Mode`. It's not you, it's just.. past experience working with someone's code where everything had a `Mode`, and `Mode` could be just about anything. So today I'm left with a severe reluctance to call something `Mode`. Maybe `Mode` is fine, but I'd prefer `MessageDisplayMode`, or `MessageMode`, or `ProgressMessageMode`... anything.

---

I don't like the `m` and `e` prefixes. The enum is easy to fix; the private fields though...

> ```
> Private mMode As ePBarModeType
> Private mCurrentProgress As Long
> Private mSteps As Long
> ```

I know you've more than once commented on why I'm doing this, but I'd recommend shoving them into a `Private Type` - that way you can call them the same thing as the property they're backing:

```
Private Type TProgressBarMembers
    Mode As ePBarModeType
    CurrentProgress As Long
    Steps As Long
End Type
```

...and only have a single private field:

```
Private this As TProgressBarMembers
```

---

I don't like underscores either. The class itself is called `Form_ProgressBar`... VBA uses the underscore to denote event handlers and interface implementations; using it in an identifier feels wrong.

I'd rename the enum to something like this:

```
Public Enum ProgressBarDisplayMode
    DisplayPercent
    DisplayExecuting 
End Enum
```

Note that you don't need to specify any values when the first member's value is 0.

---

Overall I like the idea, but I find the names could use some fine-tuning. Other than that, you only have a few minor tweaks to make that code easier to extend, well done!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was too close to it. The only thing to note is the class name. Access automagically prepends all forms with `Form_`. There's nothing I can do about that one. I'll be taking a lot of your advice though. Spot on about the setter doing more than just setting.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the final version of the code here for anyone interested.

```
Option Explicit

' ***************************************************************
' Class: Form_ProgressBar 
' Popup progress bar 
' 
' Author: Christopher J. McClellan 
'     http://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/
' Significant input from Mat's Mug 
'     http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug
'
' Published under Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 
' http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ 
'
' You are free to change, distribute, and pretty much do 
'  whatever you like with the code, but you must give credit 
'  to the original author and publish any derivative of this 
'  code under the same license. 
' ***************************************************************

Public Enum ProgressBarDisplayMode
    PBarDisplayPercent
    PBarDisplayExecuting
End Enum

Private Type TProgressBarMembers
    Mode As ProgressBarDisplayMode
    CurrentProgress As Long
    Steps As Long
End Type

Private Const maxBoxWidth As Long = 7200
Private Const executingMessage As String = "Executing..."

Private this As TProgressBarMembers

Public Property Get PercentComplete() As Double
'read only
    PercentComplete = this.CurrentProgress / this.Steps * 100
End Property

Public Property Let Mode(newValue As ProgressBarDisplayMode)
    this.Mode = newValue
End Property

Public Property Get Mode() As ProgressBarDisplayMode
    Mode = this.Mode
End Property

Public Property Let CurrentProgress(newValue As Long)
    this.CurrentProgress = newValue
    ' keep the graphics in sync
    RepaintMe
End Property

Public Property Get CurrentProgress() As Long
    CurrentProgress = this.CurrentProgress
End Property

Property Let Steps(newValue As Long)
    this.Steps = newValue
End Property

Public Sub Init(Steps As Long, Mode As ProgressBarDisplayMode, Optional Caption As String = "Loading...")
    Me.Mode = Mode
    Me.Caption = Caption
    this.CurrentProgress = 0
    this.Steps = Steps
    Me.boxProgress.Width = 0

    Select Case Mode
        Case PBarDisplayExecuting
            Me.txtStatus = executingMessage
        Case Else
            Me.txtStatus = "Ready"
    End Select

    Me.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub RepaintMe()

    If Not this.Mode = PBarDisplayExecuting Then
        UpdateProgressMessage
    End If

    UpdateBoxWidth

    Me.Repaint
    DoEvents
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateProgressMessage()
    Select Case this.Mode
        Case PBarDisplayPercent
            ' format #0 makes a 1 or 2 digit number without decimals
            Me.txtStatus = Format(Me.PercentComplete, "#0") & " % Complete"
        Case PBarDisplayExecuting
            Me.txtStatus = executingMessage
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateBoxWidth()
    Me.boxProgress.Width = (this.CurrentProgress / this.Steps) * maxBoxWidth
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mat's Mug covered the issues with the form/class itself pretty well](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/62365/41243), but I'd like to mention a few things about `exampleCall2()`. This is boilerplate code that will be used anytime you call a long running `ADODB.Command`. It's absolutely worth extracting it into a method that takes in a command as an argument.

```
Private Sub ExecuteWithProgressBar(cmd as ADODB.Command)

    DoCmd.HourGlass True

    'must execute command async
    cmd.Execute , , adAsyncExecute

    Dim pbar As New Form_ProgressBar
    Dim i As Long
    pbar.init 10000, PBarMode_Executing, ""

    Do While cmd.STATE = adStateExecuting
        For i = 0 To 10000
            pbar.CurrentProgress = i
        Next i
    Loop
    Set pbar = Nothing

    DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

Which still leaves a few issues to be dealt with.

1. You're messing with the UI, so you ***need*** to have an error handler that turns the hour glass mouse pointer back off. While you're at it, make sure to `Set pbar = nothing` to make sure it's removed from the screen.
2. This comment isn't very helpful.

   ```
   'must execute command async
   ```

   Of course we have to execute asynchronously! It's so obvious! Wait... Why do we have to execute async??? Try this instead.

   ```
   'must execute command async so 
   ' the code doesn't wait for cmd 
   ' to finish before showing pbar
   ```
3. Instead of hard coding the status message and number of steps to take, use some optional parameters with default values.

`ExampleCall1` is boilerplate code too, but much harder to get rid of without delegates (which [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) doesn't support). Any attempt to do so would probably cause more harm than good in my opinion.